# Is there a way to change the selection in the Editor Attributes window, while maintaining current selection?

Tags: arcobjects, attribute-table, .net

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to alter the selection within the Editor Attributes window while maintaining the current selection set.  In the image below, I've manually selected an item in the selection set so that attributes of the item are visible.

[image: Editor Attribute Window]

I was hoping to programmatically alter the selected item so that attributes of the newly selected item it would be visible in the attributes window.  I've seen the [AttributeWindow Interface](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00200000004r000000) and the [TableSelection Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/TableSelectionAction_Property/000v0000019w000000/) but these don't seem to do what I'd like, unless I've missed something. Is there another interface that I'm missing?

Comment: To my knowledge they share the same SelectionSet, so in short no. However there's nothing stopping you making a tree-view/2 column table display that looks like it and maintaining your own FeatureSelection (responding of course to SelectionChanged event).